# WP rest api: How to get number of comments

Tags: json, wordpress

I read all the Wordpress WP rest api document but i did not find how to limit the numbers of comments i want. 
I tryed. http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/posts/999/comments?filter[comments_per_page]=1

Comment: Is it possible for you to use [version 2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're able to use version 2 of the Rest API, then the endpoint is something like the following:

```
domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=1&per_page=2
```

where the `post` parameter is the ID of the post for which you're retrieving the comments and `per_page` is how many to show. If you want a list of all comments, and limit them, then:

```
domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?per_page=2
```

You can also append a page parameter to show a different paged value of comments thus:

```
domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=1&per_page=2&page=3
```

which would return the 5th and 6th comments (page 3 of comments when there are 2 per page) for the post with an ID of 1

Comment: You can only get a maximum of 100 comments each request. If you want to know how many comments a post has, you have to get the x-wp-total on the response headers.

Comment: Thank you @RichardTape I was wondering how to implement lazy loading with WP API and your answer made it clear to me.